# Date Command in Cron after Midnight

Tags: bash, date, cron, cron-task

I would like to ask you a question about date command behavior in cron jobs. I have a bash script which is full of date command which executes in crontab every day at 23:00 like;

```
day=$(date +%d) #today
day1=$(date +%d -d "+1 day") #tomorrow
```

There is a wget command inside this script which uses these "date" commands. Downloading data with wget command lasts like 45 minutes and after completion of downloading data, there are a few commands which uses "date" commands and they do not last till to the 00:00.

However, downloading will be longer (approximately 1.5 hours) until today because of my internet issues so downloading part will end at next day 00:30, so commands with "date" after downloading part will change. Hence, should i configure date commands after downloading part or date commands are embedded in cron whenever it starts.

In other words, for instance, my "day" variable has been set as 15 at 23:00. After passing midnight will this "day" variable be set as 16 or will it continue as 15?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: How about maintaining a variable at the beginning of the job and keep using/passing it throughout the script to maintain the consistency in dates or a temporary file can be used to write date in the beginning and in subsequent calls date can be read from that file?

Comment: Thank you for your open-minded comment Jyoti Dhiman. However, in order to do this I should wait for one day. Even though, I can do it by manipulating the time of computer; I simply would like to ask to this community.

Comment: There doesn't seem to be a question in your original post.  Could you edit it to include a question?

Comment: Ok, I added a question mark to my last sentence. Sorry for forgetting it.

Comment: you are setting values to variables. You would  have to re-execute`day=$(date +%d)`later in your script for the value to change. If you files are being delivered with dates appended and  you need to test for that, then you'll have to add code to allow for a changed date. As is, it's hard to tell exactly what you are doing, so I don't think people will be able to help further. Read about [mcve] and think how that applies to improving your Q. Good luck!

Comment: I agree with @shellter. It sounds like you have a misconception about `day=$(date +%d)`. The `date` command is run only once. The day variable will remain at that value unless it is explicitly changed later. Reading the variable will not cause it to be updated.

Comment: shelter and UncleCarl; thank you for your understandings. You're absolutely right. Sorry to bother you.